# Most efficient way to read text file and dump content into JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, java-io, jtextcomponent

I am curious what the most efficient way is to read a text file (do not worry about size, it is reasonably small so `java.io` is fine) and then dump its contents into a `JTextArea` for display.

E.g. can I somehow consume the entire file in a single string and then use `JTextArea.setText` to display it or should I read line by line or byte arrays and populate them into a StringBuffer and then set the text area to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) and pass it a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html). Just do this:

**Java 7** -- try-resource block

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("myfile.txt")) {
    textArea.read(reader, null);
}
```

**Java 6** -- try-finally block

```
FileReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new FileReader("myfile.txt");
    textArea.read(reader, null);
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than reading the full contents of the file, you could allow the `JTextArea` component to use a `Reader` to read the file's `InputStream`:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
textArea.read(fr, null);
```